# Why is everything is acted on in the "if" and nothing acted on in the "then" in this Bash script?

Tags: bash, if-statement

Trying to test if file size is zero from a list of files echo a message about that file, else do several other operations on files that have some contents.

My list of files contains only one file with zero bytes. However upon finding that file, every file is acted upon as if they all had zero bytes.

```
for f in $(cat suffixes.txt)
    do
       if [ ! -s "$f" ] ;
       then
           echo *.$f exists with size zero bytes
       else
           echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++"
           echo for file *.f$
           echo number of lines equals
           cat *.$f | wc -l
           echo occurences of \"trade\" in file equals
           grep -o trade *.$f | wc -l
           echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++"
       fi
    done
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Don't you mean `if [ -e "$f" ] && [ ! -s "$f" ]`? If you don't test the `-e`, you don't know what the `! -s` is telling you.

Comment: Also, you're testing for a file named `"$f"`, not a file whose name *ends in* `*.f`, with your test.

Comment: ...see BashFAQ #4 for info on checking for existence of files with a given extension: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004

Answer (score 1):

Going by your comments, you would need two loops:

```
for s in $(cat suffixes.txt);
  do for f in *.$s;
do
  [[ $f == "*.$s" ]] && break;    # File with this suffix non-existent
  if [ ! -s "$f" ] ;
  then
    echo $f exists with size zero bytes
  else
    echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    echo for file $f
    echo number of lines equals
    cat $f | wc -l
    echo occurences of \"trade\" in file equals
    grep -o trade $f | wc -l
    echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++"
  fi
  done
done
```

First time meeting this type of code tag, hope it looks ok.

Comment: `for x in $(cat ...)` is bad form. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Also, it would be more conventional to write `[[ -e "$f" ]] || break` -- that way you don't need to embed the glob two places in your code and have to worry about updating it in more than place if requirements change.

Comment: Actually was wondering about the trade-off between a string comparison and a test for file existence.

Comment: ...the third approach being to set the `nullglob` option and then have a non-matching glob return no items at all rather than itself. The only real disadvantage to that is the need to turn it off later to avoid other code behaving unexpectedly